# RISC-V toolchain + googletest: undefined reference to `getcwd', `mkdir`

Tags: linker, gnu, googletest, riscv

I am trying to build googletest with the RISC-V gnu toolchain.

I understand that for a baremetal target certain gtest features must be disabled. I managed to get rid of undefined references to `regexec` etc by declaring the following in my toolchain file:

```
add_compile_definitions(GTEST_HAS_POSIX_RE=0 GTEST_HAS_CLONE=0 GTEST_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 GTEST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE=0 GTEST_HAS_STREAM_REDIRECTION=0 GTEST_HAS_RTTI=0)
```

However, I still get the errors:

```
/opt/riscv/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/13.2.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: ../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): in function `.L0 ':
gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x296): undefined reference to `getcwd'
/opt/riscv/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/13.2.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: gtest-all.cc:(.text+0xce0): undefined reference to `mkdir'
```

How can I resolve this? I have seen github issues where people define stubs for these functions, but I have attempted this without success, as I am trying to avoid having the gtest code locally, and instead use the FetchContent cmake module. This makes it hard to integrate the stubs I made.

Is there another gtest option to work around this problem?

Comment: I don't think gtest has _any_ support for bare metal systems. You'll probably have to disable _all of it_ before you can successfully link.

Comment: I see, could you advise about how I might go about unit testing a software library for baremetal then? I just have some functions where I want to check the result is still correct when compiled for different targets. Some functions will be implemented with  custom instructions on some targets.